# Applying Unique over columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have data having over 385 features, to find uniques for a column i have used `df.unique()` function.
However I have to find unique values over all 385 columns.

I tried using for loop as under,

```
col = [df_train.columns]

for i in col:
    print(i.unique())
```

I'm getting an output as under

```
Index(['ID', 'y', 'X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X8',
       ...
       'X375', 'X376', 'X377', 'X378', 'X379', 'X380', 'X382', 'X383', 'X384',
       'X385'],
      dtype='object', length=366)
```

However the above are the columns names of the dataset and not the unique values of each columns.

I'm doing a concept error when I'm applying for loop, it would be appreciated to correct me where I'm going wrong or an alternative method to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in df_train.columns:
    print(df_train[i].unique())
```

If you do

```
print(df_train.columns)
```

It will give you only column names

eg.  `["x0","x1","x2"]` etc

You need to use indexing to access column values like `df_train["column_name"]`

Comment: If you have time, can you please explain where did I go wrong in my above code? So that I can avoid concept errors going further.

Answer (score 0):

to find `unique` values in a `dataframe`, we can use `describe` method as follows

```
df.describe().loc['unique']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the `unique()` method per column:

```
col = df.columns.values.tolist()
unique_vals_list = []

for column in col:
    unique_vals_list.append(list(df[column].unique()))
```

Your `unique_vals_list` will now contain all the unique value per column. This will be a list of list, so per index is actually the same index of your dataframe.

So accessing all unique for your first column will have the syntax:

```
unique_vals_list[0]
```

Accessing the 2nd column unique values:

```
unique_vals_list[1]
```

And so on.